# ImageIcon en JLabel - Java

Tags: java, imageicon

¿Por qué no me inserta la imagen de forma correcta?

Agregar unas imágenes a un `**JLabel**` en **Java Swing.**

**Código:**

```
private void combo_comunidadesItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                                   
        //Guardamos en una variable string el valor seleccionado del combo_comunidades.
        String comunidad = (String) combo_comunidades.getSelectedItem();
        String capital = null;
        //Si el index del combo_comunidades es cero, NO existe comunidad: deshabilitamos.
        if(combo_comunidades.getSelectedIndex()==0) {
            combo_provincias.setEnabled(false);
            textfield_capital.setEnabled(false);
            label_foto.setEnabled(false);
        }else if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            //Habilitamos.
            combo_provincias.setEnabled(true);
            textfield_capital.setEnabled(true);

            //Creamos un ArrayList de String para las provincias.
            ArrayList<String> provincias = new ArrayList<String>();
            //Devolvemos las provincias dada una comunidad.
            provincias = Conexiones.cargar_provincias(comunidad);

            //Recorremos el ArrayList de provincias.
            Iterator<String> i = provincias.iterator();
            //Limpiamos los valores anteriores del combo_provincias.
            combo_provincias.removeAllItems();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                //Añadimos a los items con cada provincia.
                combo_provincias.addItem(i.next());
            }

            //Devolvemos las provicinas dada una comunidad.
            capital = Conexiones.capital_de_comunidad(comunidad);
            textfield_capital.setText(capital);

            //Ponemos la foto de la comunidad seleccionada.
            label_foto.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/imagenes/"+comunidad+".png"));

            /*URL url_foto = this.getClass().getResource("/imagenes/"+comunidad+".png");
            ImageIcon ico_foto = new ImageIcon(url_foto);
            label_foto.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ico_foto.getImage().getScaledInstance(label_foto.getWidth()-10, label_foto.getHeight()-10, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
        */
        }
    }
```

**¿Por qué no carga la imagen?**

De hecho si descomento la parte del código:

```
   URL url_foto = this.getClass().getResource("/imagenes/"+comunidad+".png");
   ImageIcon ico_foto = new ImageIcon(url_foto);
    label_foto.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ico_foto.getImage().getScaledInstance(label_foto.getWidth()-10, label_foto.getHeight()-10, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
```

En este caso me carga la bandera, pero me la coloca en blanco y negro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todas las imágenes son de tipo `.png` y están en una misma carpeta llamada "imagenes".

Comment: y si intentas poner a `ico_foto.getImage()` en una variable de tipo por ejemplo buffered image de tipo ARGB antes de escalar?

Comment: @RuslanLópez Buffered Image? No conozco esa propiedad. Puedes poner un ejemplo de la imagen

Comment: no es una imagen es un tipo de dato ;)

Comment: @RuslanLópez No he encontrado ningún modelo de ejemplo para resolver mi problema con Buferred image ARGB.

Comment: @RuslanLópez He encontrado este código que sirve para crear una imagen en memoria: BufferedImage imagen = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB); pero en mi caso no es crearla, sino dibujarla

Comment: Intenta con algo como esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605248/java-converting-image-to-bufferedimage

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107891/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-ruslan-lopez).

Comment: @RuslanLópez No consigo resolverlo, si puedes abre "debate al chat"...